Whatsapp Webhook callback error. The callback URL or verify token couldn't be validated. Please verify the provided information or try again later
While configuring webhook callback URL getting error "The callback URL or verify token couldn't be validated. Please verify the provided information or try again later."


please assist.
In Postman requst am getting "hubChallenge" as plain text


The issue seems to be the data type of the returned hub.challenge variable. Make sure you return it as an int or any numerical datatype instead of a string.
